# Scriptable object instances not working at random moments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so I launched my game and my scriptable instances looked normal in the assets :
[assets screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb1SK.png)
But sometimes, at random moments, my instances become like this :
[scriptable objects looking weird](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV7o4.png)
And when I change random things in my scripts, like adding a space in a comment, of whatever, it sometimes works again but sometimes not. It tells to six compile Errors but i have no compile errors in the console :
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTKg7.png)
The problem is that the instances don't work when They look like this.

I cannot build the project :
[console when I build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Heg.png)

I tried to reassign the scriptable object to the instance, but the problem reoccurs each time. Tell me if you need more inf

Comment: Please do not post screen shots.

Comment: Out of interest, did you rename the scriptable object code at some point?  I think I did that once and it caused similar havoc in my project and I had to completely delete and recreate those items.

Comment: @Brad why ? How can I explain if I don't post screenshots ?

Comment: @syp5w2qxe No the name of the class and the name of the script are the same

Comment: Copy and paste the code/error messages.  See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example